# How to force cTAKES to put to store the UMLS in RAM?

Tags: nlp, ctakes

I am processing a batch of documents using [Apache cTAKES](http://ctakes.apache.org/) through the CPE Configurator. My pipeline includes `UmlsDictionaryLookUpAnnotator`. For each document, `UmlsDictionaryLookUpAnnotator` re-reads the UMLS from the hard drive.

This results in `UmlsDictionaryLookUpAnnotator` taking most of the running time:

[image]

and making many I/Os:

[image]

How to force cTAKES to put to store the UMLS in RAM?

I tried to increase the memory allocated to cTAKES, from the default 3 GB to ~8 GB, but it did not help:

```
java -Dctakes.umlsuser=MY_UMLS_USERNAME -Dctakes.umlspw=MY_UMLS_PASSWORD -cp "%CTAKES_HOME%/desc/;%CTAKES_HOME%/resources/;%CTAKES_HOME%/lib/*" -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/%CTAKES_HOME%/config/log4j.xml -Xms512M -Xmx8g org.apache.uima.tools.cpm.CpmFrame
```